# Why only either of $A^{-1}A$ and $AA^{-1}$ is equal to identity matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

Consider $6\times 4$ matrix $A$.

Why either of $A^{-1}A$ and $AA^{-1}$ is equal to identity matrix, but the other one is not equal to identity matrix?

Note: I try to do it numerically as follows. But I don’t understand why I get such a result. I see it’s mathematical explanation in order to convenience. 
[image]

Comment: What's $A^{(-1)}$?

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer homework questions - you are more likely to get help from people if you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3554844/edit) in your thoughts so far. Do you have any examples of where this occurs?

Comment: This is not homework question. I just try it numerically. And I reached such a result. I don’t see why? @lioness99a

Comment: @Gae.S. it is inverse of Matrix A.

Comment: The way it is written, it sounds like a homework question so is likely to attract downvotes and close votes. Can you edit in the steps you took to come across this result, to give it some context

Comment: @B11b I know the inverse of a square matrix, not the inverse of a rectangular matrix.

Comment: @B11b: "inverse of Matrix A" is ambiguous for a non-square $A$. What definition have you used in your numerical experiments?

Comment: Oh okay. I don’t know your explanation. I added my trial. Please give me a proof or explanation for that. Thanks a lot. @Blue

Comment: @B11b: What software is that? And what documentation is there for the notation `A/A` vs `A\A`? (Comments are easily overlooked, so please always add clarifying details to the question itself.)

Comment: @Blue I use Matlab. A\A=$ A^{-1}A$ and $A/A= AA^{-1}$

Comment: @B11b: Then we're back to the ambiguity of the inverse for a non-rectangular matrix. What does Matlab's documentation have to say about its default implementation of such a thing?

Comment: I think I get such a result because of non-square matrix. Right? @Blue

Comment: A nonsquare matrix doesn't have an inverse. It may have a one-sided inverse, but can't have a two-sided inverse. Easiest way to see why is to think about a $1\times2$ matrix.

Comment: @B11b: Certainly, if $A$ were square, then the traditional inverse would satisfy $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$. So, yes: getting different results for your $A$ is "because" it is non-square. However, without knowing how Matlab calculates the "inverse" of a non-square matrix, it's difficult to explain the differing results. This seems to be more of a *Matlab* question than a *mathematical* one. ("Extended discussion" warning. I have no Matlab experience, so I'll conclude my participation here. Good luck!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse is defined for square matrices and it is unique. For rectanglar matrices
either right or left inverse exists and it is also not unique.
For $A_{6 \times 4}$ if B is the inverse of $A$, then $$A_{6 \times 4} B_{4 \times 6}=I_{6 \times 6}~~~~~(1)$$ Here $B$ has 24 unknowns whereas there are 36 equations. This system of equations is over-determined so left inverse of $A$ cannot exist.
Next, let $C$ be the right inverse, then
$$C_{4\times 6} A_{6 \times 4} =I_{4\times 4}~~~~~~(2)$$
Here there are 24 unknown elements of $C$ and there are only 16 linear simultaneous equations. So there are many solutions and this makes the right inverse to exist but it will not be unique.

So, here in your example, Eq.(1) is not possible, but (2) is possible and there will be many matrices for $C$.

Also note that $A$ is horizonatal matrix, $B$ is vertical (but here it doesn't exist) $C$ is again vertical it exists but it is non uinque. So a horizontal matric will have a vertical matrix as its inverse which is either left or right.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So helpful for me!

Comment: But, your notation is a bit different. In the Wikipedia, C is left inverse, B is right inverse.

Comment: This really does not matter, dear.  I will see Wikipedia show me the link.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix $A$ is injective but not surjective. Therefore there exists a left inverse for $A$ which is a $4 \times 6$ matrix $B$ such that $$BA = I_{4}$$

If we also had $$AB = I_{6}$$
this would imply that $A$ is surjective, which is false.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is ver good explanation for me.